# "Untar" file on iPhone

Tags: iphone, tar, zlib, archive-tar

I'm writing an iPhone app which downloads a tar-gzipped file from a Webserver, then needs to unarchive this file so that it can be copied into the app's Documents folder.

I'm using tar/gzip because I want to download a whole bunch of small files in one HTTP request, to make everything nice and fast.

I've investigated solutions like http://www.feep.net/libtar/, but as a C/Objective-C newb, I can't get any of them to compile for the iPhone platform.

(I felt like I should just be able to do a system call to "tar -zxvf myfile.tar.gz", but it would appear it's not that easy!)

So is there a simple way to just un-tar a file on the iPhone? Or am I going about this all wrong, and is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Nik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This blog post should help you:
http://blog.hawkey.org/?p=332

EDIT: [Google cache version of the same page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cache:blog.hawkey.org/?p=332) which actually links to a [forum post here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7615-simple-objective-c-class-zip-unzip-zip-format-files.html) which links to a [Google Code project here](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/), containing some code which implements unzipping on iOS.

Comment: Yeah, I've gone the .zip route - it's a ton easier :D

Comment: This link is no longer valid =/.  Please fix it or add what it said to this answer if possible.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a light untar library for iOS : https://github.com/mhausherr/Light-Untar-for-iOS

Complete blog post about the solution : http://blog.octo.com/en/untar-on-ios-the-pragmatic-way/

Hope this helps,
Vincent

Answer (score 1):

I took a different approach by building `libarchive` and `bz2lib` as a static library for iOS. You can find it here:

http://github.com/davepeck/iOS-libarchive/

Comment: 404 page not found.