# Convert gz to zip format

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

Is possible do convert GZ to ZIP format use objective-c?

```
NSFileManager *fileManger = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
paths = nil;
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"text.zip"];

if([fileManger fileExistsAtPath:path ] == NO){
NSString *testPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"text" ofType:@"gz"];
[fileManger copyItemAtPath:@"" toPath:@"" error:&error]; 
}
```

converted gz file from mainBundle to zip file placed to docuemtn directory.

But can not open zip file by ZipArchive class.

Comment: *What* is compressed within the `.gz` file?  Is it `tar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[gzip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) is only compressing data, while [ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) is both a compressor and archiver. A gzip stream can only compress one file while ZIP can compress several. So simply renaming the file cannot work.

You need to [decompress the gzip stream to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740820/how-to-uncompress-a-gzip-file-and-write-that-out-to-an-uncompressed-file-on-iph), then [recompress as ZIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286496/how-can-i-create-a-zip-file-by-using-objective-c).

Comment: Often `.gz` is used with `tar`, so there is that.  However the solution is to unpack into a temporary directory and re-pack that directory using `zip`.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Right. But you'd either need to know/expect the file to be a `tar.gz/tgz` file or check by inspecting the decompressed file before you can [untar the file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811608/untar-file-on-iphone) .